# Android SQLite Database primary key query

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have successfully created a database in my android app. It has a primary key called registration number which the user inputs while registering with my app. Everything works fine but if two users enter the same registration number, the account does not get created and an exception is thrown as such:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column registration_number 
is not unique (code 19)
```

This is fine. I want the app to behave like this. But how do i inform the user that this registration number is not available?
My code:

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int database_version=1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Aliah.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_info";
public static final String REGISTRATION_NUMBER = "registration_number";
public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
public static final String USER_PASS = "user_pass";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";


public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d("Databse operations", "Database created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {

    try{
    sdb.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME +" (registration_number VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, user_name VARCHAR, user_pass VARCHAR,  email VARCHAR);");
    Log.d("Databse operations", "one row inserted");}catch(SQLException e){};
    }
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop,String registration_number,String name,String pass,String email){

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(REGISTRATION_NUMBER,registration_number);
    cv.put(USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(USER_PASS,pass);
    cv.put(EMAIL,email);
    long k = SQ.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    Log.d("Databse operations", "One row inserted");

}

public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop){

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {REGISTRATION_NUMBER, USER_NAME, USER_PASS, EMAIL};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    return CR;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `insertOrThrow` instead of `insert`. This way, you can catch the `SQLException` it may throw and do what you want (in this case, inform the user about it).

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)

Answer (score -1):

You are using column name `registration_number` as `PRIMARY KEY` and the value of `registration_number` should be `unique`.

Its better to add another column `id` which is `INTEGER` and use this `id` as `PRIMARY KEY`.

**Use below method to check duplicate `registration number`:**

```
public boolean isExistRegistrationNumber(String regNumber) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do 
        {
            String registrationNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(REGISTRATION_NUMBER)));

            if(registrationNumber.equals(regNumber))
                return true;

        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Update `DatabaseOperations` class as below:**

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int database_version=1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Aliah.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_info";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String REGISTRATION_NUMBER = "registration_number";
public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
public static final String USER_PASS = "user_pass";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";


public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d("Databse operations", "Database created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {

    try {
        sdb.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME +" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, registration_number VARCHAR, user_name VARCHAR, user_pass VARCHAR,  email VARCHAR);");
        Log.d("Databse operations", "one row inserted");}catch(SQLException e){};
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop,String registration_number,String name,String pass,String email){

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(REGISTRATION_NUMBER,registration_number);
    cv.put(USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(USER_PASS,pass);
    cv.put(EMAIL,email);
    long k = SQ.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d("Databse operations", "One row inserted");

}

public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop){

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {REGISTRATION_NUMBER, USER_NAME, USER_PASS, EMAIL};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    return CR;

}

public boolean isExistRegistrationNumber(String regNumber) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do 
        {
            String registrationNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(REGISTRATION_NUMBER)));

            if(registrationNumber.equals(regNumber))
                return true;

        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Finally, `uninstall` and `reinstall` your application and try again `inserting` data into your database.

Hope this will work~

Comment: May i know the reason of downvoting?